# Объясните доходчиво, что такое побитовая операция and?

Tags: pascal

Почему 233 and 95 равно 73?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And - это побитовая операция, т. е. числа представляется в виде двоичного кода, и там, где в коде обеих чисел 1, там и будет 1 в результате, в остальных случаях - 0. Пример:

```
1000110
And
0110101
-------
0000100
```

Поэтому число And то же самое число = это же число (x And x = x).

P.S. And применяется только для целых чисел.